# How to generate strings and check if contains not permitted characters in a better way

Tags: ruby, regex

How to Generate strings and check if  contains not permitted characters in a better way

The valid character rule is

> "A-Z,a-z,0-9,!,#,$,%,-,.,@, ^,_,~,\,/,;,:,?,{,[,],},`,*,),(,+,|"

I want to use the rule to generate "valid " strings and "invalid" strings

And how to check if a string contain any character out of the rule ?
If the string contains any character out of the rule it should return false.

For generating "valid" strings

Here is my idea

Make a list containing the each valid character,and then call sample method to generate valid string.

But how to generate a string contains invalid character and check if a string is invalid ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @sawa: Your comment might be found a bit rude by some people. English is not the mother tongue for everybody here... (like me !).  Why the term "educated"?

Comment: @xav Nor is it the mother tongue for me. For such basic thing, mother tongue is irrelevant.

Comment: @sawa - mother tongue is relevant here, if it french, for example: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101106195753AAl47EQ

Comment: @UriAgassi That is why I wrote "in English text".

Comment: @sawa - an educated person whose mother tongue is french might very well put a space before a question mark in English text - because it is not his mother tongue...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a valid string by creating an array of valid characters, then using it to sample characters in your string:

```
VALID_CHARACTERS = ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a  + %w<! # $ % - . @  ^ _ ~ \\ / ; : ? { [ ] } ` * ) ( + |>

def create_valid_string(length)
  length.times.map { VALID_CHARACTERS.sample }.join
end

create_valid_string(12)
# => "w?r~@f:+vl1r"
```

To check whether a string is valid, you should make sure that all of its characters are included in the valid characters:

```
def string_valid?(string)
  string.chars.all? { |c| VALID_CHARACTERS.include? c }
end

string_valid? "w?r~@f:+vl1r"
# => true

string_valid? "w?r~@ f:+vl1r"
# => false
```

To create an invalid string you need to... add a character not in the valid characters?

```
SOME_INVALID_CHARACTERS = [',', ' ']

def create_invalid_string(length)
  invalid_characters = (1...length).to_a.sample.times.map { SOME_INVALID_CHARACTERS.sample }
  valid_characters = create_valid_string(length - invalid_characters.length).chars
  (invalid_characters + valid_characters).shuffle.join
end

create_invalid_string(12)
# => "UZ*rT6T,![H,"
```